# Gradle does not work with spring boot sample app. Why not?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I am using this spring boot tutorial to study spring boot.  I followed the steps explicitly, but now gradle is not working.  I recall installing gradle in the CentOS 7 devbox in which this is being run.  **How can I get gradle to launch this sample app?**

Here is the terminal log 
typed from the root directory of the app created using the exact steps in the tutorial listed above:

```
[root@localhost gs-actuator-service]# ./gradlew bootRun --stacktrace
-bash: ./gradlew: No such file or directory
[root@localhost gs-actuator-service]# ./gradlew bootRun --debug --stacktrace
-bash: ./gradlew: No such file or directory
[root@localhost gs-actuator-service]# ./gradlew bootRun
-bash: ./gradlew: No such file or directory
[root@localhost gs-actuator-service]#
```

I also confirmed that gradle is installed on the machine by typing the following:

```
[root@localhost gs-actuator-service]# gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.10
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-12-21 21:15:04 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     276bdcded730f53aa8c11b479986aafa58e124a6

Groovy:       2.4.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_45 (Oracle Corporation 25.45-b02)
OS:           Linux 3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64 amd64

[root@localhost gs-actuator-service]#
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `./gradlew`, of course it only works, when the Gradle Wrapper is included in that sample project, i.e. if the script `gradlew` exists in the root directory of that project. If you want to use your local Gradle installation, execute it like that:

```
gradle bootRun
```

Comment: Thank you and +1 for the fast and correct response.